# Polar coordinates, Differentiation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates

Can someone clarify this step for me please,

"The polar coordinate r satisfies $r^2=x^2+y^2$, so by differentiating with respect to t we get $r\cdot\dot r=x\cdot\dot x+y\cdot\dot y$"

I am totally lost...and I realize this should be simple, I'm just missing something..

Comment: You have just to consider $r$, $x$, and $y$ as functions of $t$, i.e. $r=r(t)$, $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$. Then to derive, say $r^2$, you have to derive the composition of r as a function of $t$ and the square: $\frac{d}{dt} (r^2)=2r\cdot \dot r$.

Comment: Note that $\dot r$ is another way of writing $r'$ or $\frac{\operatorname d\!r}{\operatorname d\!t}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use implicit differentiation $$r^2(t) = x^2(t) + y^2(t) \Rightarrow 2r(t)r' = 2x(t)x' + 2y(t)y' \Rightarrow r r' = x x'+yy'$$

Answer (score 2):

Write it explicitly: $\frac{d}{dt}(r(t)^2) = 2 \times r(t) \times \frac{dr}{dt}$ Same treatment for the other two.